Matplotlib broke after Ubuntu update
I just updated Ubuntu to 24.04.1 LTS and I'm having some trouble with Matplotlib in my Anaconda Python setup. Most of the other scientific libraries I use appear to be fine.
I'll try to run
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.hist(np.random.normal(10))

and I get
plt.hist(np.random.normal(10))
Out[7]: 
(array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
 array([8.40468485, 8.50468485, 8.60468485, 8.70468485, 8.80468485,
        8.90468485, 9.00468485, 9.10468485, 9.20468485, 9.30468485,
        9.40468485]),
 <BarContainer object of 10 artists>)Error in callback <function _draw_all_if_interactive at 0x7ff6a0b9cc20> (for post_execute), with arguments args (),kwargs {}:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py:268 in _draw_all_if_interactive
    draw_all()

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/_pylab_helpers.py:131 in draw_all
    manager.canvas.draw_idle()

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py:1905 in draw_idle
    self.draw(*args, **kwargs)

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py:387 in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py:95 in draw_wrapper
    result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py:72 in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py:3161 in draw
    self.patch.draw(renderer)

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py:72 in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.py:632 in draw
    self._draw_paths_with_artist_properties(

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.py:617 in _draw_paths_with_artist_properties
    renderer.draw_path(gc, *draw_path_args)

  File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py:131 in draw_path
    self._renderer.draw_path(gc, path, transform, rgbFace)

ValueError: object __array__ method not producing an array

Numpy version: 1.26.4
Matplotlib version: 3.9.1

Does it work when you run it from terminal? I think, the problem is in Spyder and not in your Python modules.

@jabaa no it still breaks. I tried running it in interactive mode as well as putting it all in a .py script.

Do you get the same error stack even when you run it in a file from terminal? The error stack suggests, that the update broke something with the backend. Can you try a different backend? https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/figure/backends.html
